# Connect a voltage regulator to another regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm trying to create a circuit that uses 3.3 and 5v.

I'm thinking about use a 9v battery, a 7805 to get 5v and a LM3940 connected to the 7805 to get 3.3v. But I can use the LD1117 connected direct to battery to get 3.3v. Some sites says that if I do this (9v to 3.3v) the LD1117 can get too hot.

Some sensors that I'm using I can connect directly to the battery.

What is best in terms of consumption?

Comment: What current do the regulators have to supply to their respective loads?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of consumption it's the same. There is some power that will be dissipated by one or another LDO. Why not taking a DC/DC module for 5V?